# What happens when credit card expires on recurring paypal payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

On recurring paypal payment, what happens when CC expires?

Will it send IPN notification?
Will it send email to seller and buyer?
Will it be stopped till CC is not updated and continues when it get updated?

what exactly will happen, many thing is dependent on payment on sites.

Answer (score 3):

When a credit card is going to expire the buyer needs to update their billing information. They buyer will get an e-mail from PayPal saying it is going to expire and asks the user to update their billing information.

If the buyer does not update their billing details the payment will probably fail. The reason it may not fail is because they may have money in their PayPal account or another funding source. And IPN post would be sent for the failed payment.

If the buyer does update their credit or debit card information before the Recurring Profile bills you should receive the payment successfully.

Comment: What will happens if site is down at the time of ipn hit? will paypal send ipn again

Comment: Yes, paypal sends IPN until it gets a HTTP 200. If your site is down it will be either 40x or 50x.

Comment: IPN retries only 8 times.
You can manually click on "retry", within PayPal's interface.